# Converting hundreds of jpg to PDF using Terminal

Tags: command-line, format-conversion

I know that the command [`convert *.jpg myPdf1.pdf`](https://wlborg.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/convert-jpgs-to-a-pdf-on-a-mac-from-the-terminal-or-the-services-menu/) can convert multiple JPEG files into a single PDF.

But I would like to convert multiple JPEGs into multiple PDFs, for example:

```
myJPG1.jpg → myPDF1.pdf
myJPG2.jpg → myPDF2.pdf
myJPG3.jpg → myPDF3.pdf
```

Is there any decent way to manage something like that?

Comment: How would you order them?

Comment: Well suppose they are called myJPG1, myJPG2 and so on, and you want to convert them to myPDF1, myPDF2 and so on.

Comment: The question isn't clear, do you have multiple jpgs or pdfs? You **can** convert multiple jpgs to a single pdf using the command you have used in your question.

Comment: It should be clearer now, I just want a bunch of PDF's with names myPDF1 myPDF2 and so on. But Your suggestion, into a single PDF, also sounds nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My first instinct for batch processing files is almost always `find`. It's excellent if you need to build in any sort of filtering (which you don't here) but it's still a favourite. This will also recurse into subdirectories unless you tell it (with `-maxdepth 1` or other):

```
find -name '*.jpg' -exec convert "{}" "{}.pdf" \;
rename 's/\.jpg\.pdf$/.pdf/' *.jpg.pdf
```

The `find`/`convert` statement will output a load of `.jpg.pdf` files. The second cleans this up.

---

Perhaps a slightly more elegant approach in such a simple case:

```
for file in *.jpg ; do convert "$file" "${file/%jpg/pdf}"; done
```

This doesn't recurse and you don't have to mess around cleaning up the filenames.

---

And I almost forgot, ImageMagick has a numerical output which might fit your use-case perfectly. The following will just stick a three-digit identifier  (`000`, `001`, `002`, etc) on the end of the "myPDF":

```
convert *.jpg myPDF%03d.pdf
```

Obviously if you're dealing with more than a thousand entries, increase the number. If you don't want it zero-padded, remove the leading zero.

Comment: find -name '*.jpg' | parallel 'convert {} {.}.pdf'

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, **`convert`** changes the image quality before "packing it" into the PDF. So, to have minimal loss of quality, is better to put the original `jpg`, (***works with `.png` too***) into the PDF, you need to use `img2pdf`.

I use these commands:

With time I discovered a simpler, shorter **one liner solution also using `img2pdf` that doesn't need `pdftk` as in the original answer**

1. Make PDF

   `img2pdf *.jp* --output combined.pdf`
2. (optional) OCR the output PDF

   `ocrmypdf combined.pdf combined_ocr.pdf`

---

Below is the **original** answer commands with more command and more tools needed:

---

1. This to make a `pdf` file out of every `jpg` image without loss of either resolution or quality:

   ls -1 ./*jpg | xargs -L1 -I {} img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf
2. Here you will have the `*.pdf`s as `*.jpg.pdf`, so will do a little renaming

   mmv "*.jpg.pdf" "#1.pdf"

You need to have installed img2pdf and mmv

```
sudo apt install img2pdf mmv
```